# How to inject from application context into a mock in Junit5 Mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I must implement an Unit Test for `MyUtility.class` in my Java application. However, It has a dependency on `MyConfig.class` (It fetches configuration properties from `application.yml` file).

```java
class MyUtility {

  MyConfig myConfig;

  @Autowired
  public MyUtility(MyConfig myConfig) {
   this.myConfig = myConfig;
  }

  public String methodA() {

    ... // use myConfig.getValue() to perform some operation

    methodB(); // call methodB()

    ...
  }

  public String methodB() { ... }
}
```

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
class MyConfig {

  String value; // to map test.value from application.yml
}
```

Using *JUnit5*, I'm trying to test the functionality `methodA`. But, I don't need to test `methodB` . Hence, I'm mocking the response of `methodB`.

```java
class ApplicationTests {

  @Mock
  MyConfig myConfig;

  @Mock
  MyUtility myUtility;

  ...

  @Test
  public void testMethodA() {

    Mockito.when(myUtility.methodB()).thenReturn("someValue");
    ...
  }
}
```

Since I've to mock `MyUtility`, I'm also having to mock `MyConfig` since it's a dependency (else `myConfig` shows up as `null`). But I don't want to mock `MyConfig`. I want `methodA` to use the value that is present in the `application.yml` file rather than mocking it.

Is it possible to inject the `MyConfig` from the application context into `MyUtility` mock ?

Comment: Hi, why are you mocking your `Utility` class? If it's the class you're testing, it shouldn't be mocked, right? It seems you may be in need of a [@Spy](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html)

Comment: I'm trying to test `methodA` of the utility class. But I don't wish to test `methodB` that is being called internally by `methodA`. `methodB` makes a Http request. I wish to mock the response of `methodB` so as to avoid a network call, and just test the functionality of `methodA`

Comment: To intercept the method call to methodB, you will need some sort of proxy around it, e.g. a Mockito Spy. [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) may also be useful if you want to mock the remote server you're calling over HTTP. If you need to replace a bean in the Spring context, [@MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) may help you out

Comment: But there is no way to autowire inside a mock? So if there are any other dependencies a mock is using, we must mock them as well?

Comment: You aren't mocking `MyUtility` you are mocking the `MyConfig` which is then injected in a real instance of `MyUtility`. So you aren't mocking what you think you are mocking.

Comment: @M.Deinum That's correct. My bad. I've updated the code. What I meant to ask is, since I wish to mock `methodB` of `MyUtlity`, I'm having to create a mock of the entire utility. Due to which, I'm also having to mock `MyConfig`. But by mocking `MyConfig`, I can no longer fetch the "real" values present in the yml file. Will it be possible to autowire the `MyConfig` class in the `MyUtility` mock?

Comment: If you are mocking `MyUtility` there is no need to mock the `MyConfig` as the implementation doesn't matter anymore. Why do you want to mock that specific method? Seems like you are solving this problem at the wrong level.

Comment: The methods of `MyUtility` use properties present in `MyConfig` class. If I could autowire `MyConfig` into the mocked `MyUtility`, the code would work fine. The reason I am mocking that specific method is because that method (`methodB`) is making a network call and returning a response back to `methodA`. I don't care about the network call. I just wish to test the functionality of `methodA`. So I'm trying to mock `methodB` to give a response to `methodA` so that it can go forward with other implementation without having to worry about the network call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I could autowire MyConfig into the mocked MyUtility, the code would work fine.

As long as you use the `SpringExtension` and setup your configuration/context correctly you can do that. Instead of mocking `MyConfig` add the autowired config to your testclass and pass that one to your creation of the `MyUtility` class.

> The reason I am mocking that specific method is because that method (methodB) is making a network call and returning a response back to methodA. I don't care about the network call.

The problem is that you currently mock the class (and not only the method). As `@PaulBenn` already mentioned you want to use `@Spy` instead of `@Mock`.

A methodcall on a [spy](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) uses the real implementation as long as you have not defined different behaviour for it. A spy is normally created on a pre-existing instance
of the object so all dependencies should be setup normally.

```java
class ApplicationTests {

    @Mock
    MyConfig myConfig;

    @Test
    public void testMethodA() {

        ...
        MyUtility spy = Mockito.spy(new MyUtility(myConfig));
        Mockito.when(spy.methodB()).thenReturn("someValue");

        spy.methodA();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This should solve the problem. I wasn't very sure regarding mocking a spy earlier.